# json-simple containerFactory

Tags: java, json-simple

Using the decoding example with the containerFactory, I get the following output:

```
[{DeviceType=foo, DeviceName=foo1, IPAddress=192.168.1.1, UserName=admin, Password=pw},     {DeviceType=foo, DeviceName=foo2, IPAddress=192.168.1.2, UserName=admin, Password=pw}]
```

These are the entries that are outputted when entry.getValue() is called.

How do I get the data out from these objects?

For example, how would I get the value of DeviceName.

```
Map obj = (Map)parser.parse(new FileReader("example.yml"),containerFactory);

Iterator iter = obj.entrySet().iterator();

//Iterator iterInner = new Iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());                                
            }

            //System.out.println("==toJSONString()==");
            //System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(json));

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch(ParseException pe){
            System.out.println(pe);
          }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try finding out what classes the values are with `System.out.println(entry.getValue().getClass())` (or inspect it in debugger) and the values to actual classes. From the output it looks like `List<Map<String, String>>` or something.

Comment: Ahhhh...good idea! The output is class java.lang.String. Is there a way in the first parser.parse statement to key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

```
//The innermost data is in a LinkedHashMap
//I hope this snippet helps someone
while(iter.hasNext)
    {
        LinkedList entry = (LinkedList)iter.next();
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getValue().getClass());
        myList = (LinkedList) (entry.getValue());
        System.out.println(myList);
        Iterator iterate = myList.iterator();
        while (iterate.hasNext())
        {
            LinkedHashMap entry2 = (LinkedHashMap)iterate.next();
            System.out.println(entry2.get("DeviceName"));

        }

}
```